# DFA for language

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, finite-automata

I want to give a DFA for the language which contains the words X ∈ {0,1,2}* for which the number of 0's + number of 1's is even AND the number of 1's + the number of 2's is odd.

I tried many automatons so far but I haven't succeeded with any.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Can you construct DFAs for either of those conditions separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Whether or not a word $u$ belongs to your language only depends on the parity of two parameters: $x(u) = |u|_0 + |u|_1$ and $y(u) = |u|_1 + |u|_2$. Computing modulo $2$, this gives you four states, $(0, 0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$. It remains to find the transitions. For this, you just have to compute $x(uc)$ and $y(uc)$ for each letter $c \in \{0, 1, 2\}$.